# Why does eclipse force me to use a final?

Tags: java, constructor, final

I have a constructor with `size` as a parameter.  Eclipse forces me to declare `Integer size` as final. Why ?

```
   public LRUCache(final Integer size) {
        lhm = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
                return size() > size;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size` is a reference to an `Integer` object. When you do

```
size() > size
```

you are dereferencing `size` to get its `int` value. Because `removeEldestEntry` happens at in a different context, at a different time, there needs to be some guarantee that the reference you are using is the same you are declaring. Therefore you need `final`, ie. so the reference cannot change.

In [the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but
>   not declared in an inner class must be declared final.

[and](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html)

> Each local variable (§14.4) and every blank final field (§4.12.4,
>   §8.3.1.2) must have a definitely assigned value when any access of its
>   value occurs.

[and](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.6)

> V is definitely assigned before an anonymous class declaration
>   (§15.9.5) that is declared within the scope of V iff V is definitely
>   assigned after the class instance creation expression that declares
>   the anonymous class.

Comment: Sorry, but while your references are right, but your explanation is off. You make no mention of the anonymous class having to make a copy of the local variable which is the whole crux of the problem here. I'm not sure why this answer was accepted.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I believe that's what I meant with _there needs to be some guarantee that the reference you are using is the same you are declaring_

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse isn't forcing anything. **Java** requires that local variables be declared *final* if they're used in anonymous inner classes. These classes make copies of any local variable used, and if the variable is not final, the original and the copy may be referring to a different value.

Comment: Nit: It's not a general requirement per-se (wrt the "may be referring to a different value") that this occurs; it is how the Java specifications defines it. Many languages with closures allow modifications of the bound bindings - anon inner classes are just a "poor man's substitute", and this one of the restrictions.

Comment: @user2864740: it is currently a *Java Requirement*, and you are correct, that this is how Java is defined. This may change with Java 8.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it's not a Java requirement. I've reworked the language on my initial comment.

Comment: Exploring how Java currently "rewrites" the anon inner classes in context of local-final variables would provide some insight as to why these semantics are as they are - which might be covered in similar answers.